# Using subs on a List

Tags: python, list, sympy

Hi everyone I'm running a small python program that solves some equations, the problem arises when I obtain the first result solving the first equation for D and I have that D depends on A and C, and then I use subs on the next equation with the previous result, but sympy doesn't let me do da that, so how can I manipulate this result and make subs possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
import sympy as sp

g, a, A, C, D, K, x = sp.symbols("g a A C D K x")

X=(A*sp.cos(g*x/a))+(sp.sin(g*x/a))+(C*sp.exp(-g*x/a))+(D*sp.exp(-g*(a-x)/a))

dx1=sp.diff(X,x,1)

dx2=sp.diff(X,x,2)

eq1= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,0),0)
eq2= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,0)/dx1.subs(x,0),K)
eq3= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,a),0)
eq4= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,a)/dx1.subs(x,a),-K)

D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)
eq33=D1.subs(D,D1)
C33=sp.solve(eq33,C)
Df=D1.subs(C,C33)
eq22=sp.subs(eq2,[C,D],[C33,D11]);
A22=solve(eq22,A)
pretty(A22)
```

Comment: Oh sorry thats a mistake its D1

Comment: There is a edit function, use it to clean up your code. What is `D11`? What are you trying to accomplish with `;`? Used to c programming? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sympy as sp

g, a, A, C, D, K, x = sp.symbols("g a A C D K x")

X=(A*sp.cos(g*x/a))+(sp.sin(g*x/a))+(C*sp.exp(-g*x/a))+(D*sp.exp(-g*(a-x)/a))

dx1=sp.diff(X,x,1)

dx2=sp.diff(X,x,2)

eq1= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,0),0)
eq2= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,0)/dx1.subs(x,0),K)
eq3= sp.Eq(X.subs(x,a),0)
eq4= sp.Eq(dx2.subs(x,a)/dx1.subs(x,a),-K)

D1=sp.solve(eq1,D)
eq33=D1[0].subs(D,D1)
C33=sp.solve(eq33,C)
Df=D1[0].subs(C,C33[0])
eq22=eq2.subs((C,D),(C33[0],D1[0]))
A22=sp.solve(eq22,A)
sp.pprint(A22)
```

This should work. You can get an object from a list by simply calling `D1[0]` for the first object of that list. Note that there might be multiple solutions and hence multiple entries in `D1`.